# elasticsearch multi-token keyword synonyms

Tags: elasticsearch, synonym

I'm trying to implement simple multi-token synonyms in Elasticsearch, but not getting the results I expect.  Here's some curl:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test" -d'
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "blah": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "my_synonyms"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "my_syn_filt": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [
              "foo bar, fooo bar"
            ]
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "my_synonyms": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "my_syn_filt"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Index a few documents:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/my_type/1 -d '{"blah": "fooo bar"}'
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/my_type/2 -d '{"blah": "fooo barr"}'
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/my_type/3 -d '{"blah": "foo bar"}'
```

Now query:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test/_search" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "blah": "foo bar"
    }
  }
}'
```

I'm expecting to get back documents 1 and 3, however, only get back 3.   Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Upon further inspection I'm also not getting the expected tokens when calling the analyzer directly:

```
curl 'localhost:9200/test/_analyze?analyzer=my_synonyms' -d 'fooo bar'
```

Returns only one token, "fooo bar", when I'm expecting two tokens: "fooo bar" and "foo bar".

Comment: Is it me, or document 1 has "blah": "fooo bar"? with an extra `o`?

Comment: The extra o is intentional.  It's just an arbitrary choice for the synonym.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like if you did a search for 'fooo bar' instead, you will get documents 1 and 3. To get the results you were expecting, you will have to flip your synonym terms to go the other way:

"fooo bar => foo bar"

The arrow tells ES to add terms on the right side as synonyms for all terms on the left. If you want them to go bi-directional, you can simply do 'fooo bar, foo bar' and make sure expand is not explicitly set to false.

Comment: querying on either still only returns one document.  furthermore, I changed the synonym to use a comma instead of => and the results are still the same--only one identical hit for either query. I think the fact that the _analyze query stated in the end only returns one token is the key to the underlying problem

Comment: Took another look and found one other thing to change. The synonym filter uses the whitespace tokenizer by default. You will have to explicitly set the synonym filter's tokenizer to 'keyword' for the dictionary to pick up your value as a whole. Otherwise, it will break up your phrase into 'foo' and 'bar' before ES does a lookup into the dictionary.